# What does mastering a weapon mean?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

Periodically, post-fight, I will get a message saying "Character so and so has mastered weapon such and such".

What does that mean? What sort of perks does mastering a weapon give, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use unleash skills of weapons until you unlock them by filling the mastery bar.  By maxing it out, you'll fully unlock the weapon.  You can see the list of unleashes and which you have unlocked simply by inspecting the weapon.

(I believe a mastered weapon has a marginally higher unleash rate as well, but I'm really not sure about this.)